# Error in installation of rhc gem

Tags: rubygems, openshift

When i run command "gem install rhc" i get the following error

ERROR:  Error installing rhc:
        invalid gem: package is corrupt, exception while verifying: undefined           method `size' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) in C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/cache/rhc-1.38.4.gem

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an older version of Ruby, try 1.9.3 or 2.0.  The OpenShift RHC Gem has issues with Ruby 2.2

Comment: thank you for reply. I did exactly what you said but after that when i run the command "gem install rhc" again then i get this error.                                        ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rhc' (>= 0) in any repository

Comment: and also this error : ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
    too many connection resets (http://rubygems.global.ssl.fastly.net/latest_specs.4.8.gz)

Comment: What version of ruby did you try? Make sure you updated your path to point to the new ruby installation also